# splitting a mulipage tiff and recursively saving each tiff with an amended suffix

Tags: python, operating-system, python-imaging-library

I have thousands of tiff files which are mulitpage tiff.  I have already annotated the file name with metadata describing what the tiff is.  I would now like to split the multipage tiff into single tiff images.
I created a new directory for the mulitpage tif, but don't know how to recursively name the new tifs in the img.save and move the files to a new folder.  It works by running shutil 2x.  Has to be a cleaner

```
from PIL import Image
import os, shutil
# make destination folder
os.makedirs("multipage_tif")
dest1 = ".\multipage_tif"
#split multipage tifs
for dirpath, dirs, files in os.walk("."): 
  for filename in files:
    fname = os.path.join(dirpath,filename)
    if fname.endswith('.tif'):
        img = Image.open(filename)
        fn, fext = os.path.splitext(filename)
        for i in range(2):
            try:
                img.seek(i)
                img.save(fn+'_page_%s.tif'%(i,))
            except EOFError:
                break
#move split files to the destination folder
for dirpath, dirs, files in os.walk("."): 
  for filename in files:
        if filename.endswith('page_1.tif'): 
            shutil.move(os.path.join(dirpath,filename), os.path.join(dest1,filename))
for dirpath, dirs, files in os.walk("."): 
  for filename in files:
        if filename.endswith('page_0.tif'): 
            shutil.move(os.path.join(dirpath,filename), os.path.join(dest1,filename))
```

Comment: look for the quote marks, and count the parens

Comment: You can even see where the error is color coded, because you didn't correctly put quotes around the filename.